Execution failed for task 'app:checkReleaseDuplicateClasses'
I am just trying to build my project but I got these errors every time, I've tried many ways to solve it like clean and rebuild etc. but I couldn't. I want to launch the app on Play Store.
build.gradle (app)
plugins {
    alias(libs.plugins.android.application)
    alias(libs.plugins.compose.compiler)
    alias(libs.plugins.kotlin)
    alias(libs.plugins.kotlin.ksp)
    alias(libs.plugins.google.gms.google.services)
    alias(libs.plugins.google.firebase.crashlytics)
}

android {
    namespace = "com.shaadow.tunes"
    compileSdk = 35

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId = "com.shaadow.tunes"
        minSdk = 22
        targetSdk = 35
        versionCode = 9
        versionName = "9.1"
        versionNameSuffix = "Tiger"
        multiDexEnabled = true
    }

    splits {
        abi {
            reset()
            isUniversalApk = true
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        debug {
            applicationIdSuffix = ".debug"
        }

        release {
            isMinifyEnabled = true
            isShrinkResources = true
            proguardFiles(
                getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android-optimize.txt"),
                "proguard-rules.pro"
            )
            signingConfig = signingConfigs.getByName("debug")
        }
    }

    sourceSets.all {
        kotlin.srcDir("src/$name/kotlin")
    }

    buildFeatures {
        compose = true
    }

    compileOptions {
        isCoreLibraryDesugaringEnabled = true
        sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_17
        targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_17
    }

    kotlinOptions {
        freeCompilerArgs += "-Xcontext-receivers"
        jvmTarget = "17"
    }
}

ksp {
}

dependencies {
    implementation(platform(libs.compose.bom))
    implementation(libs.compose.activity)
    implementation(libs.compose.coil)
    implementation(libs.compose.material.icons)
    implementation(libs.compose.material3)
    implementation(libs.compose.navigation)
    implementation(libs.compose.shimmer)
    implementation(libs.compose.ui)
    implementation(libs.compose.ui.util)
    implementation(libs.core.splashscreen)
    implementation(libs.exoplayer)
    implementation(libs.lifecycle.viewmodel.compose)
    implementation(libs.reorderable)
    implementation(libs.room)
    implementation(libs.firebase.messaging)
    implementation(libs.firebase.inappmessaging.display)
    implementation(libs.firebase.crashlytics)
    implementation(libs.firebase.analytics)
    implementation(libs.core)
    implementation(libs.activity.ktx)
    ksp(libs.room.compiler)
    implementation(projects.innertube)
    implementation(projects.kugou)
    coreLibraryDesugaring(libs.desugaring)
    implementation(libs.gradle)
    implementation(libs.retrofit)
    implementation(libs.converter.gson)
    implementation(libs.dexter)
    implementation(libs.google.auth.library.oauth2.http)
}

build.gradle (root)
plugins {
    alias(libs.plugins.android.application) apply false
    alias(libs.plugins.android.library) apply false
    alias(libs.plugins.compose.compiler) apply false
    alias(libs.plugins.kotlin) apply false
    alias(libs.plugins.kotlin.serialization) apply false
    alias(libs.plugins.kotlin.ksp) apply false
    alias(libs.plugins.kotlin.jvm) apply false
    alias(libs.plugins.google.gms.google.services) apply false
    alias(libs.plugins.google.firebase.crashlytics) apply false
}

subprojects {
    tasks.withType<org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinCompile>().configureEach {
        compilerOptions {
            if (project.findProperty("enableComposeCompilerReports") == "true") {
                arrayOf("reports", "metrics").forEach {
                    freeCompilerArgs.addAll(
                        "-P",
                        "plugin:androidx.compose.compiler.plugins.kotlin:${it}Destination=${layout.buildDirectory.asFile.get().absolutePath}/compose_metrics"
                    )
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

values.xml (C:.......gradle\caches\8.10.2\transforms\7e06bebd85fb51936f09c4f40\transformed\coil-base-2.7.0\res\values\values.xml)
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <item name="coil_request_manager" type="id"/>
</resources>

Error:
1: Task failed with an exception.
-----------
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:checkReleaseDuplicateClasses'.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.CheckDuplicatesRunnable
   > Duplicate class com.google.api.Advice found in modules proto-google-common-protos-2.17.0.jar -> proto-google-common-protos-2.17.0 (com.google.api.grpc:proto-google-common-protos:2.17.0) and protolite-well-known-types-18.0.0.aar -> protolite-well-known-types-18.0.0-runtime (com.google.firebase:protolite-well-known-types:18.0.0)
     Duplicate class com.google.api.Advice$1 found in modules proto-google-common-protos-2.17.0.jar -> proto-google-common-protos-2.17.0 (com.google.api.grpc:proto-google-common-protos:2.17.0) and protolite-well-known-types-18.0.0.aar -> protolite-well-known-types-18.0.0-runtime (com.google.firebase:protolite-well-known-types:18.0.0)
     Duplicate class com.google.api.Advice$Builder found in modules proto-google-common-protos-2.17.0.jar -> proto-google-common-protos-2.17.0 (com.google.api.grpc:proto-google-common-protos:2.17.0) and protolite-well-known-types-18.0.0.aar -> protolite-well-known-types-18.0.0-runtime (com.google.firebase:protolite-well-known-types:18.0.0)
     Duplicate class com.google.api.AdviceOrBuilder found in modules proto-google-common-protos-2.17.0.jar -> proto-google-common-protos-2.17.0 (com.google.api.grpc:proto-google-common-protos:2.17.0) and protolite-well-known-types-18.0.0.aar -> protolite-well-known-types-18.0.0-runtime (com.google.firebase:protolite-well-known-types:18.0.0)
     Duplicate class com.google.api.AnnotationsProto found in modules proto-google-common-protos-2.17.0.jar -> proto-google-common-protos-2.17.0 (com.google.api.grpc:proto-google-common-protos:2.17.0) and protolite-well-known-types-18.0.0.aar -> protolite-well-known-types-18.0.0-runtime (com.google.firebase:protolite-well-known-types:18.0.0)
     Duplicate class com.google.api.AuthProto found in modules proto-google-common-protos-2.17.0.jar -> proto-google-common-protos-2.17.0 (com.google.api.grpc:proto-google-common-protos:2.17.0) and protolite-well-known-types-18.0.0.aar -> protolite-well-known-types-18.0.0-runtime (com.google.firebase:protolite-well-known-types:18.0.0)
          Duplicate class com.google.rpc.LocalizedMessage$1 found in modules proto-google-common-protos-2.17.0.jar -> proto-google-common-protos-2.17.0 (com.google.api.grpc:proto-google-common-protos:2.17.0) and protolite-well-known-types-18.0.0.aar -> protolite-well-known-types-18.0.0-runtime (com.google.firebase:protolite-well-known-types:18.0.0)
     Duplicate class com.google.rpc.LocalizedMessage$Builder found in modules proto-google-common-protos-2.17.0.jar -> proto-google-common-protos-2.17.0 (com.google.api.grpc:proto-google-common-protos:2.17.0) and protolite-well-known-types-18.0.0.aar -> protolite-well-known-types-18.0.0-runtime (com.google.firebase:protolite-well-known-types:18.0.0)
     Duplicate class com.google.rpc.LocalizedMessageOrBuilder found in modules proto-google-common-protos-2.17.0.jar -> proto-google-common-protos-2.17.0 (com.google.api.grpc:proto-google-common-protos:2.17.0) and protolite-well-known-types-18.0.0.aar -> protolite-well-known-types-18.0.0-runtime (com.google.firebase:protolite-well-known-types:18.0.0)
     Duplicate class com.google.rpc.PreconditionFailure found in modules proto-google-common-protos-2.17.0.jar -> proto-google-common-protos-2.17.0 (com.google.api.grpc:proto-google-common-protos:2.17.0) and protolite-well-known-types-18.0.0.aar -> protolite-well-known-types-18.0.0-runtime (com.google.firebase:protolite-well-known-types:18.0.0)
     Duplicate class com.google.rpc.PreconditionFailure$1 found in modules proto-google-common-protos-2.17.0.jar -> proto-google-common-protos-2.17.0 (com.google.api.grpc:proto-google-common-protos:2.17.0) and protolite-well-known-types-18.0.0.aar -> protolite-well-known-types-18.0.0-runtime (com.google.firebase:protolite-well-known-types:18.0.0)
     Duplicate class com.google.rpc.PreconditionFailure$Builder found in modules proto-google-common-protos-2.17.0.jar -> proto-google-common-protos-2.17.0 (com.google.api.grpc:proto-google-common-protos:2.17.0) and protolite-well-known-types-18.0.0.aar -> protolite-well-known-types-18.0.0-runtime (com.google.firebase:protolite-well-known-types:18.0.0)
     Duplicate class com.google.rpc.PreconditionFailure$Violation found in modules proto-google-common-protos-2.17.0.jar -> proto-google-common-protos-2.17.0 (com.google.api.grpc:proto-google-common-protos:2.17.0) and protolite-well-known-types-18.0.0.aar -> protolite-well-known-types-18.0.0-runtime (com.google.firebase:protolite-well-known-types:18.0.0)
     Duplicate class com.google.rpc.PreconditionFailure$Violation$Builder found in modules proto-google-common-protos-2.17.0.jar -> proto-google-common-protos-2.17.0 (com.google.api.grpc:proto-google-common-protos:2.17.0) and protolite-well-known-types-18.0.0.aar -> protolite-well-known-types-18.0.0-runtime (com.google.firebase:protolite-well-known-types:18.0.0)
     Duplicate class com.google.rpc.PreconditionFailure$ViolationOrBuilder found in modules proto-google-common-protos-2.17.0.jar -> proto-google-common-protos-2.17.0 (com.google.api.grpc:proto-google-common-protos:2.17.0) and protolite-well-known-types-18.0.0.aar -> protolite-well-known-types-18.0.0-runtime (com.google.firebase:protolite-well-known-types:18.0.0)
     Duplicate class com.google.rpc.PreconditionFailureOrBuilder found in modules proto-google-common-protos-2.17.0.jar -> proto-google-common-protos-2.17.0 (com.google.api.grpc:proto-google-common-protos:2.17.0) and protolite-well-known-types-18.0.0.aar -> protolite-well-known-types-18.0.0-runtime (com.google.firebase:protolite-well-known-types:18.0.0)
     Duplicate class com.google.rpc.QuotaFailure found in modules proto-google-common-protos-2.17.0.jar -> proto-google-common-protos-2.17.0 (com.google.api.grpc:proto-google-common-protos:2.17.0) and protolite-well-known-types-18.0.0.aar -> protolite-well-known-types-18.0.0-runtime (com.google.firebase:protolite-well-known-types:18.0.0)
     Duplicate class com.google.rpc.QuotaFailure$1 found in modules proto-google-common-protos-2.17.0.jar -> proto-google-common-protos-2.17.0 (com.google.api.grpc:proto-google-common-protos:2.17.0) and protolite-well-known-types-18.0.0.aar -> protolite-well-known-types-18.0.0-runtime (com.google.firebase:protolite-well-known-types:18.0.0)
     Duplicate class com.google.rpc.QuotaFailure$Builder found in modules proto-google-common-protos-2.17.0.jar -> proto-google-common-protos-2.17.0 (com.google.api.grpc:proto-google-common-protos:2.17.0) and protolite-well-known-types-18.0.0.aar -> protolite-well-known-types-18.0.0-runtime (com.google.firebase:protolite-well-known-types:18.0.0)
     Duplicate class com.google.rpc.QuotaFailure$Violation found in modules proto-google-common-protos-2.17.0.jar -> proto-google-common-protos-2.17.0 (com.google.api.grpc:proto-google-common-protos:2.17.0) and protolite-well-known-types-18.0.0.aar -> protolite-well-known-types-18.0.0-runtime (com.google.firebase:protolite-well-known-types:18.0.0)
     Duplicate class com.google.rpc.QuotaFailure$Violation$Builder found in modules proto-google-common-protos-2.17.0.jar -> proto-google-common-protos-2.17.0 (com.google.api.grpc:proto-google-common-protos:2.17.0) and protolite-well-known-types-18.0.0.aar -> protolite-well-known-types-18.0.0-runtime (com.google.firebase:protolite-well-known-types:18.0.0)
     Duplicate class com.google.rpc.QuotaFailure$ViolationOrBuilder found in modules proto-google-common-protos-2.17.0.jar -> proto-google-common-protos-2.17.0 (com.google.api.grpc:proto-google-common-protos:2.17.0) and protolite-well-known-types-18.0.0.aar -> protolite-well-known-types-18.0.0-runtime (com.google.firebase:protolite-well-known-types:18.0.0)
     Duplicate class com.google.rpc.QuotaFailureOrBuilder found in modules proto-google-common-protos-2.17.0.jar -> proto-google-common-protos-2.17.0 (com.google.api.grpc:proto-google-common-protos:2.17.0) and protolite-well-known-types-18.0.0.aar -> protolite-well-known-types-18.0.0-runtime (com.google.firebase:protolite-well-known-types:18.0.0)
     Duplicate class com.google.rpc.RequestInfo found in modules proto-google-common-protos-2.17.0.jar -> proto-google-common-protos-2.17.0 (com.google.api.grpc:proto-google-common-protos:2.17.0) and protolite-well-known-types-18.0.0.aar -> protolite-well-known-types-18.0.0-runtime (com.google.firebase:protolite-well-known-types:18.0.0)
     Duplicate class com.google.rpc.RequestInfo$1 found in modules proto-google-common-protos-2.17.0.jar -> proto-google-common-protos-2.17.0 (com.google.api.grpc:proto-google-common-protos:2.17.0) and protolite-well-known-types-18.0.0.aar -> protolite-well-known-types-18.0.0-runtime (com.google.firebase:protolite-well-known-types:18.0.0)
     Duplicate class com.google.rpc.RequestInfo$Builder found in modules proto-google-common-protos-2.17.0.jar -> proto-google-common-protos-2.17.0 (com.google.api.grpc:proto-google-common-protos:2.17.0) and protolite-well-known-types-18.0.0.aar -> protolite-well-known-types-18.0.0-runtime (com.google.firebase:protolite-well-known-types:18.0.0)
     Duplicate class com.google.rpc.RequestInfoOrBuilder found in modules proto-google-common-protos-2.17.0.jar -> proto-google-common-protos-2.17.0 (com.google.api.grpc:proto-google-common-protos:2.17.0) and protolite-well-known-types-18.0.0.aar -> protolite-well-known-types-18.0.0-runtime (com.google.firebase:protolite-well-known-types:18.0.0)
     Duplicate class com.google.rpc.ResourceInfo found in modules proto-google-common-protos-2.17.0.jar -> proto-google-common-protos-2.17.0 (com.google.api.grpc:proto-google-common-protos:2.17.0) and protolite-well-known-types-18.0.0.aar -> protolite-well-known-types-18.0.0-runtime (com.google.firebase:protolite-well-known-types:18.0.0)
     Duplicate class com.google.rpc.ResourceInfo$1 found in modules proto-google-common-protos-2.17.0.jar -> proto-google-common-protos-2.17.0 (com.google.api.grpc:proto-google-common-protos:2.17.0) and protolite-well-known-types-18.0.0.aar -> protolite-well-known-types-18.0.0-runtime (com.google.firebase:protolite-well-known-types:18.0.0)
     Duplicate class com.google.rpc.ResourceInfo$Builder found in modules proto-google-common-protos-2.17.0.jar -> proto-google-common-protos-2.17.0 (com.google.api.grpc:proto-google-common-protos:2.17.0) and protolite-well-known-types-18.0.0.aar -> protolite-well-known-types-18.0.0-runtime (com.google.firebase:protolite-well-known-types:18.0.0)
     Duplicate class com.google.rpc.ResourceInfoOrBuilder found in modules proto-google-common-protos-2.17.0.jar -> proto-google-common-protos-2.17.0 (com.google.api.grpc:proto-google-common-protos:2.17.0) and protolite-well-known-types-18.0.0.aar -> protolite-well-known-types-18.0.0-runtime (com.google.firebase:protolite-well-known-types:18.0.0)
     Duplicate class com.google.rpc.RetryInfo found in modules proto-google-common-protos-2.17.0.jar -> proto-google-common-protos-2.17.0 (com.google.api.grpc:proto-google-common-protos:2.17.0) and protolite-well-known-types-18.0.0.aar -> protolite-well-known-types-18.0.0-runtime (com.google.firebase:protolite-well-known-types:18.0.0)
     Duplicate class com.google.rpc.RetryInfo$1 found in modules proto-google-common-protos-2.17.0.jar -> proto-google-common-protos-2.17.0 (com.google.api.grpc:proto-google-common-protos:2.17.0) and protolite-well-known-types-18.0.0.aar -> protolite-well-known-types-18.0.0-runtime (com.google.firebase:protolite-well-known-types:18.0.0)
     Duplicate class com.google.rpc.RetryInfo$Builder found in modules proto-google-common-protos-2.17.0.jar -> proto-google-common-protos-2.17.0 (com.google.api.grpc:proto-google-common-protos:2.17.0) and protolite-well-known-types-18.0.0.aar -> protolite-well-known-types-18.0.0-runtime (com.google.firebase:protolite-well-known-types:18.0.0)
     Duplicate class com.google.rpc.RetryInfoOrBuilder found in modules proto-google-common-protos-2.17.0.jar -> proto-google-common-protos-2.17.0 (com.google.api.grpc:proto-google-common-protos:2.17.0) and protolite-well-known-types-18.0.0.aar -> protolite-well-known-types-18.0.0-runtime (com.google.firebase:protolite-well-known-types:18.0.0)
     Duplicate class com.google.rpc.Status found in modules proto-google-common-protos-2.17.0.jar -> proto-google-common-protos-2.17.0 (com.google.api.grpc:proto-google-common-protos:2.17.0) and protolite-well-known-types-18.0.0.aar -> protolite-well-known-types-18.0.0-runtime (com.google.firebase:protolite-well-known-types:18.0.0)
     Duplicate class com.google.rpc.Status$1 found in modules proto-google-common-protos-2.17.0.jar -> proto-google-common-protos-2.17.0 (com.google.api.grpc:proto-google-common-protos:2.17.0) and protolite-well-known-types-18.0.0.aar -> protolite-well-known-types-18.0.0-runtime (com.google.firebase:protolite-well-known-types:18.0.0)
     Duplicate class com.google.rpc.Status$Builder found in modules proto-google-common-protos-2.17.0.jar -> proto-google-common-protos-2.17.0 (com.google.api.grpc:proto-google-common-protos:2.17.0) and protolite-well-known-types-18.0.0.aar -> protolite-well-known-types-18.0.0-runtime (com.google.firebase:protolite-well-known-types:18.0.0)
     Duplicate class com.google.rpc.StatusOrBuilder found in modules proto-google-common-protos-2.17.0.jar -> proto-google-common-protos-2.17.0 (com.google.api.grpc:proto-google-common-protos:2.17.0) and protolite-well-known-types-18.0.0.aar -> protolite-well-known-types-18.0.0-runtime (com.google.firebase:protolite-well-known-types:18.0.0)
     Duplicate class com.google.rpc.StatusProto found in modules proto-google-common-protos-2.17.0.jar -> proto-google-common-protos-2.17.0 (com.google.api.grpc:proto-google-common-protos:2.17.0) and protolite-well-known-types-18.0.0.aar -> protolite-well-known-types-18.0.0-runtime (com.google.firebase:protolite-well-known-types:18.0.0)
     Duplicate class com.google.rpc.context.AttributeContext found in modules proto-google-common-protos-2.17.0.jar -> proto-google-common-protos-2.17.0 (com.google.api.grpc:proto-google-common-protos:2.17.0) and protolite-well-known-types-18.0.0.aar -> protolite-well-known-types-18.0.0-runtime (com.google.firebase:protolite-well-known-types:18.0.0)
     Duplicate class com.google.rpc.context.AttributeContext$1 found in modules proto-google-common-protos-2.17.0.jar -> proto-google-common-protos-2.17.0 (com.google.api.grpc:proto-google-common-protos:2.17.0) and protolite-well-known-types-18.0.0.aar -> protolite-well-known-types-18.0.0-runtime (com.google.firebase:protolite-well-known-types:18.0.0)
     Duplicate class com.google.rpc.context.AttributeContext$Api found in modules proto-google-common-protos-2.17.0.jar -> proto-google-common-protos-2.17.0 (com.google.api.grpc:proto-google-common-protos:2.17.0) and protolite-well-known-types-18.0.0.aar -> protolite-well-known-types-18.0.0-runtime (com.google.firebase:protolite-well-known-types:18.0.0)
     Duplicate class com.google.rpc.context.AttributeContext$Api$Builder found in modules proto-google-common-protos-2.17.0.jar -> proto-google-common-protos-2.17.0 (com.google.api.grpc:proto-google-common-protos:2.17.0) and protolite-well-known-types-18.0.0.aar -> protolite-well-known-types-18.0.0-runtime (com.google.firebase:protolite-well-known-types:18.0.0)
     Duplicate class com.google.rpc.context.AttributeContext$ApiOrBuilder found in modules proto-google-common-protos-2.17.0.jar -> proto-google-common-protos-2.17.0 (com.google.api.grpc:proto-google-common-protos:2.17.0) and protolite-well-known-types-18.0.0.aar -> protolite-well-known-types-18.0.0-runtime (com.google.firebase:protolite-well-known-types:18.0.0)
     Duplicate class com.google.rpc.context.AttributeContext$Auth found in modules proto-google-common-protos-2.17.0.jar -> proto-google-common-protos-2.17.0 (com.google.api.grpc:proto-google-common-protos:2.17.0) and protolite-well-known-types-18.0.0.aar -> protolite-well-known-types-18.0.0-runtime (com.google.firebase:protolite-well-known-types:18.0.0)
     Duplicate class com.google.rpc.context.AttributeContext$Auth$Builder found in modules proto-google-common-protos-2.17.0.jar -> proto-google-common-protos-2.17.0 (com.google.api.grpc:proto-google-common-protos:2.17.0) and protolite-well-known-types-18.0.0.aar -> protolite-well-known-types-18.0.0-runtime (com.google.firebase:protolite-well-known-types:18.0.0)
     Duplicate class com.google.rpc.context.AttributeContext$AuthOrBuilder found in modules proto-google-common-protos-2.17.0.jar -> proto-google-common-protos-2.17.0 (com.google.api.grpc:proto-google-common-protos:2.17.0) and protolite-well-known-types-18.0.0.aar -> protolite-well-known-types-18.0.0-runtime (com.google.firebase:protolite-well-known-types:18.0.0)
     Duplicate class com.google.rpc.context.AttributeContext$Builder found in modules proto-google-common-protos-2.17.0.jar -> proto-google-common-protos-2.17.0 (com.google.api.grpc:proto-google-common-protos:2.17.0) and protolite-well-known-types-18.0.0.aar -> protolite-well-known-types-18.0.0-runtime (com.google.firebase:protolite-well-known-types:18.0.0)
     Duplicate class com.google.rpc.context.AttributeContext$Peer found in modules proto-google-common-protos-2.17.0.jar -> proto-google-common-protos-2.17.0 (com.google.api.grpc:proto-google-common-protos:2.17.0) and protolite-well-known-types-18.0.0.aar -> protolite-well-known-types-18.0.0-runtime (com.google.firebase:protolite-well-known-types:18.0.0)
     Duplicate class com.google.rpc.context.AttributeContext$Peer$Builder found in modules proto-google-common-protos-2.17.0.jar -> proto-google-common-protos-2.17.0 (com.google.api.grpc:proto-google-common-protos:2.17.0) and protolite-well-known-types-18.0.0.aar -> protolite-well-known-types-18.0.0-runtime (com.google.firebase:protolite-well-known-types:18.0.0)
     Duplicate class com.google.rpc.context.AttributeContext$Peer$LabelsDefaultEntryHolder found in modules proto-google-common-protos-2.17.0.jar -> proto-google-common-protos-2.17.0 (com.google.api.grpc:proto-google-common-protos:2.17.0) and protolite-well-known-types-18.0.0.aar -> protolite-well-known-types-18.0.0-runtime (com.google.firebase:protolite-well-known-types:18.0.0)
     ...
     Duplicate class com.google.rpc.context.AttributeContext$ResourceOrBuilder found in modules proto-google-common-protos-2.17.0.jar -> proto-google-common-protos-2.17.0 (com.google.api.grpc:proto-google-common-protos:2.17.0) and protolite-well-known-types-18.0.0.aar -> protolite-well-known-types-18.0.0-runtime (com.google.firebase:protolite-well-known-types:18.0.0)
     Duplicate class com.google.rpc.context.AttributeContext$Response found in modules proto-google-common-protos-2.17.0.jar -> proto-google-common-protos-2.17.0 (com.google.api.grpc:proto-google-common-protos:2.17.0) and protolite-well-known-types-18.0.0.aar -> protolite-well-known-types-18.0.0-runtime (com.google.firebase:protolite-well-known-types:18.0.0)
     Duplicate class com.google.rpc.context.AttributeContext$Response$Builder found in modules proto-google-common-protos-2.17.0.jar -> proto-google-common-protos-2.17.0 (com.google.api.grpc:proto-google-common-protos:2.17.0) and protolite-well-known-types-18.0.0.aar -> protolite-well-known-types-18.0.0-runtime (com.google.firebase:protolite-well-known-types:18.0.0)
     Duplicate class com.google.rpc.context.AttributeContext$Response$HeadersDefaultEntryHolder found in modules proto-google-common-protos-2.17.0.jar -> proto-google-common-protos-2.17.0 (com.google.api.grpc:proto-google-common-protos:2.17.0) and protolite-well-known-types-18.0.0.aar -> protolite-well-known-types-18.0.0-runtime (com.google.firebase:protolite-well-known-types:18.0.0)
     Duplicate class com.google.rpc.context.AttributeContext$ResponseOrBuilder found in modules proto-google-common-protos-2.17.0.jar -> proto-google-common-protos-2.17.0 (com.google.api.grpc:proto-google-common-protos:2.17.0) and protolite-well-known-types-18.0.0.aar -> protolite-well-known-types-18.0.0-runtime (com.google.firebase:protolite-well-known-types:18.0.0)
     Duplicate class com.google.rpc.context.AttributeContextOrBuilder found in modules proto-google-common-protos-2.17.0.jar -> proto-google-common-protos-2.17.0 (com.google.api.grpc:proto-google-common-protos:2.17.0) and protolite-well-known-types-18.0.0.aar -> protolite-well-known-types-18.0.0-runtime (com.google.firebase:protolite-well-known-types:18.0.0)
     Duplicate class com.google.rpc.context.AttributeContextProto found in modules proto-google-common-protos-2.17.0.jar -> proto-google-common-protos-2.17.0 (com.google.api.grpc:proto-google-common-protos:2.17.0) and protolite-well-known-types-18.0.0.aar -> protolite-well-known-types-18.0.0-runtime (com.google.firebase:protolite-well-known-types:18.0.0)
     Duplicate class com.google.type.CalendarPeriod found in modules proto-google-common-protos-2.17.0.jar -> proto-google-common-protos-2.17.0 (com.google.api.grpc:proto-google-common-protos:2.17.0) and protolite-well-known-types-18.0.0.aar -> protolite-well-known-types-18.0.0-runtime (com.google.firebase:protolite-well-known-types:18.0.0)
     Duplicate class com.google.type.CalendarPeriod$1 found in modules proto-google-common-protos-2.17.0.jar -> proto-google-common-protos-2.17.0 (com.google.api.grpc:proto-google-common-protos:2.17.0) and protolite-well-known-types-18.0.0.aar -> protolite-well-known-types-18.0.0-runtime (com.google.firebase:protolite-well-known-types:18.0.0)
     Duplicate class com.google.type.CalendarPeriodProto found in modules proto-google-common-protos-2.17.0.jar -> proto-google-common-protos-2.17.0 (com.google.api.grpc:proto-google-common-protos:2.17.0) and protolite-well-known-types-18.0.0.aar -> protolite-well-known-types-18.0.0-runtime (com.google.firebase:protolite-well-known-types:18.0.0)
     Duplicate class com.google.type.Color found in modules proto-google-common-protos-2.17.0.jar -> proto-google-common-protos-2.17.0 (com.google.api.grpc:proto-google-common-protos:2.17.0) and protolite-well-known-types-18.0.0.aar -> protolite-well-known-types-18.0.0-runtime (com.google.firebase:protolite-well-known-types:18.0.0)
     Duplicate class com.google.type.Color$1 found in modules proto-google-common-protos-2.17.0.jar -> proto-google-common-protos-2.17.0 (com.google.api.grpc:proto-google-common-protos:2.17.0) and protolite-well-known-types-18.0.0.aar -> protolite-well-known-types-18.0.0-runtime (com.google.firebase:protolite-well-known-types:18.0.0)
     Duplicate class com.google.type.Color$Builder found in modules proto-google-common-protos-2.17.0.jar -> proto-google-common-protos-2.17.0 (com.google.api.grpc:proto-google-common-protos:2.17.0) and protolite-well-known-types-18.0.0.aar -> protolite-well-known-types-18.0.0-runtime (com.google.firebase:protolite-well-known-types:18.0.0)
     Duplicate class com.google.type.ColorOrBuilder found in modules proto-google-common-protos-2.17.0.jar -> proto-google-common-protos-2.17.0 (com.google.api.grpc:proto-google-common-protos:2.17.0) and protolite-well-known-types-18.0.0.aar -> protolite-well-known-types-18.0.0-runtime (com.google.firebase:protolite-well-known-types:18.0.0)
     Duplicate class com.google.type.ColorProto found in modules proto-google-common-protos-2.17.0.jar -> proto-google-common-protos-2.17.0 (com.google.api.grpc:proto-google-common-protos:2.17.0) and protolite-well-known-types-18.0.0.aar -> protolite-well-known-types-18.0.0-runtime (com.google.firebase:protolite-well-known-types:18.0.0)
     Duplicate class com.google.type.Date found in modules proto-google-common-protos-2.17.0.jar -> proto-google-common-protos-2.17.0 (com.google.api.grpc:proto-google-common-protos:2.17.0) and protolite-well-known-types-18.0.0.aar -> protolite-well-known-types-18.0.0-runtime (com.google.firebase:protolite-well-known-types:18.0.0)
     Duplicate class com.google.type.Date$1 found in modules proto-google-common-protos-2.17.0.jar -> proto-google-common-protos-2.17.0 (com.google.api.grpc:proto-google-common-protos:2.17.0) and protolite-well-known-types-18.0.0.aar -> protolite-well-known-types-18.0.0-runtime (com.google.firebase:protolite-well-known-types:18.0.0)

2: Task failed with an exception.
-----------
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:mergeReleaseResources'.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.res.ResourceCompilerRunnable
   > Resource compilation failed (Failed to compile values resource file C:\Users\surya\AndroidStudioProjects\TunesApp\app\build\intermediates\incremental\release\mergeReleaseResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml. Cause: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can not extract resource from com.android.aaptcompiler.ParsedResource@3771b06d.). Check logs for more details.


Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a minimal reproducible example.

Please provide your build.gradle files

Share your values.xml file

I moved the code from the answer to the question, but there was so much content it overflowed the 30K limit. I trimmed one of the error logs a bit.
